# JRadionButton pressed icon

Tags: image, icons, jradiobutton, pressed

I have a toolbar filled with buttons, and I want these buttons to be radio buttons, or at least respond like radio buttons. The problem that I am having with them is that I want to set an icon to these buttons, but I need the button to indent when it is pressed; radio buttons do not do this automatically. Is there a simple way to set a radio button to show an indent when pressed? Maybe I will have to make separate images for default and pressed, but I would rather not.

Answer (score 0):

Ha, I figured out a way to do it! I had to set the button border to Beveled Border, **and** make it visible. Then I added a Change Listener to the button, and changed the beveled border state there.